Comparing Firth's logistic and traditional logistic by AIC
My data has rare events so I decided to develop a Firth's penalized logistic regression using logistf package. I also want to apply a traditional ML logistic regression to compare their performance. I selected "Akaike information criterion" to compare these two models but its calculation seems different as I read here.
I want to know which one is more accurate for my data. Is it correct to use AIC? If yes, should I calculate them manually?

Firth logistic regression involves maximizing a penalized likelihood, meaning it will always have a smaller likelihood than usual logistic regression for the same model. That means it will always have a less favorable AIC, since the AIC is a function of the number of parameters in the model (which is the same between the two) and the likelihood given the estimated parameters. That doesn't mean it is the worse model.
The reasons to prefer Firth logistic regression are that it has smaller bias and smaller variance than the maximum likelihood estimates and therefore should generally be preferred over the maximum likelihood estimates. Don't bother comparing the two sets of estimates; just go with Firth.

Thank you! What about Brier Score? Does Firth necessarily have a lower BS?

It doesn't necessarily have a lower BS because the BS is not used to fit the model. You can fit a logistic regression model by minimizing the BS, but that also doesn't guarantee it is a good model. If you use any measure based on accuracy of predictions, make sure you do so using cross-validation instead of on the full dataset, since the whole point of regularizing the model is to improve performance out of sample. That said, Firth LR has lower bias and variance than ML LR, so why bother comparing them? Just use the one with the better properties.

The number of estimable parameters in the Firth-corrected regression is not the same as that of ML regression; the former will be smaller than latter. So it's not automatically true that Firth AIC (correctly calculated) will have less favorable, i.e. larger, AIC (although maybe it can be proven)

@psboonstra can you explain that further? Both methods include the same number of parameters in the model; Firth's estimator just adds a penalty term to the likelihood. The penalty does not set any parameters to exactly 0 (i.e., unlike lasso).

Consider linear regression with a ridge penalty. If using AIC to select tuning parameter, then the number of estimated parameters plugged into the AIC expression is not p but rather Tr[X(XtX+lambda*I_p)^{-1}Xt], which is always less than p even though none of the coefficients is set exactly to zero in ridge regression. See e.g. Elements of Statistical Learning Section 7.6. Same idea would apply to Firth penalized logistic regression which penalizes without setting to zero, as you noted. But since Firth logistic regression is not linear, there's not a closed form solution that I'm aware of.

Following on my previous comment: AIC was developed only for maximum likelihood (see ?stats::AIC or for more detail Burnham and Anderson (2002), Section 2.2). Clearly AIC is often applied outside of the maximum likelihood framework. But because of that my (admittedly limited understanding) tells me not to think of the offset as 'the number of non-zero parameters' or even the 'number of estimable parameters' as I wrote above but rather as the 'bias-correction term' that, when added to the log-likelihood evaluated at the estimated parameters, is trying to correct the upward (optimistic) bias.

Not sure if it's better to ask this as a new question: Is it always the case that Firth's logistic regression has smaller bias and smaller variance? Or is this statement mostly true for rare events / when there's (quasi) complete separation?

Yes, the bias and variance are always lower for Firth LR. See Rainey & McCaskey (2021).

Practical perspective:
I had something totally ridiculous happen when trying to use AIC model selection for a logistic regression that was fit with Firth penalty.
I added a complete noise predictor (random) to the dataset, refit the same model again with Firth but including the noise in the covariate list as a predictor. I got a lower AIC.
Thus, using AIC, the model with a pure noise predictor included is preferred!
